# [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError （vue and openlayers）

Tags: vue.js

I have created an application using Vue and OpenLayers' Overlay. In it, I have a set of data used to render DOM elements in Vue, and then bind these DOM elements using Overlay. However, when updating the data, some errors have occurred.

> vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."

App.vue

```
<template>
  <button @click="handleChange">Change</button>
  <div id="map" ref="mapEle">
    <Card v-for="item in locations" v-bind="item" :key="item.name" :service="map"></Card>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Card from "./Card.vue";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import "ol/ol.css";
import { Map, View } from "ol";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";


const map = ref<any>(null);
const mapEle = ref();
const locations = ref([
  { lon: 13.41, lat: 52.52, name: "Berlin" ,},
  { lon: 2.35, lat: 48.86, name: "Paris" },
  { lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51, name: "London" },
]);

const handleChange = () => {
  locations.value = [
  { lon: 2.35, lat: 48.86, name: "Paris" },
  { lon: 13.41, lat: 54.52, name: "ZhangSan" },
  { lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51, name: "London" },
  ]
}

onMounted(() => {
  const layer = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
  });

  map.value = new Map({
    layers: [layer],
    target: mapEle.value,
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2,
    }),
  });
});
</script>
```

Card.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="card" ref="root">
    {{ name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Overlay } from 'ol';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';
import { watchEffect, ref } from 'vue';


const props = defineProps<{
  name: string,
  lon: number,
  lat: number
  service: any
}>()
const root = ref()
const id = watchEffect(() => {
  if (!root.value) return;

  if (!props.service) return;
  const overlay = new Overlay({
    element: root.value,
    position: fromLonLat([props.lon, props.lat]),
  });

  props.service.addOverlay(overlay);

  id()
})

</script>
```

I suspect that the issue may be that Overlay has moved the elements, interfering with Vue's re-rendering process.

Is there a solution to this?